# Error while adding permissions to group

Tags: powershell

I used the folowing stmt to add permissions to group:

```
$spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
```

gives following error

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "This operation is not
>   allowed on an object that inherits permissions."

Regards, any suggestions/help would be higly appreciated

Ketan Gandhi.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function Create-SPGroupInWeb
{
 param ($Url, $GroupName, $PermissionLevel, $Description)
 $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url
 if ($web.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
 {
  Write-Host "Group $GroupName already exists!" -foregroundcolor Red
 }
 else
 {
  $web.SiteGroups.Add($GroupName, $web.Site.Owner, $web.Site.Owner, $Description)
  $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
  $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
  $roleDefinition = $web.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel]
  $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
  $web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
  $web.Update()
  Write-Host "Group $GroupName created successfully" -foregroundcolor Green
 }

 $web.Dispose()
}
```

For more information, you can visit 
http://snahta.blogspot.in/2012/02/powershell-and-sharepoint-permissions.html

Comment: I have already refered the same link and code...still giving me error. I am executing my code using Windows ISE

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a call to `$web.BreakRoleInheritance(true)` before adding any role assignments. The "true" means that it copies the existing permissions when it breaks inheritance, with false it starts with no permissions.